# Do While loop - generating a filename and checking if the file exists

Tags: php, while-loop

I need to be able to do a while loop that generates a filename and checks if it does not exist in the directory then should continue with the script, e.g.

```
do {
      $filename = random(18) . $fileEx;
} while(!file_exists($filename));

$move_file = move_uploaded_file($request_file['tmp_name'][$i], 'files/' . $filename);

if($move_file)
{
   // ...
```

But when I do this, it just goes into an infinite loop - no errors are thrown using `E_ALL`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should run your loop as long as the file exists, not as long as it not exists (which will be forever if you have a unique file name). Change it into

```
} while(file_exists($filename));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to do it. You should use a function that ensures you create files in an atomic way.

php has [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

Comment: Very usefull function but unfortunately cannot only adds prefix not suffix (example if you want to create a temporary .html)

Comment: Yeah, that's true. If you have full control on the content of the directory (you should) you may use the generated file as a lock. So you 1) generate the file randxyz 2) check that randxyz.html does not exist 3) create randxyz.html 4) remove randxyz. If point 2 fails (that's really bad luck!), remove the generated file and try again.